# Define raster origin so each instance of LiDAR interpolation has same grid

Tags: whitebox-gat

Is there a way to control the origin point of the resulting raster when interpolating from a LAS tile?

I have a large collection of regulate .las tiles with some overlap between tiles (1,000m tiling system with 50m overlap so 1,100m x 1,000m total tile size). I want to individually interpolate using IDW or Discrete Sibson as needed, but ensure that resulting rasters have the same underlying grid so that there is no need to re-interpolate when merging the rasters. As it stands, when i interpolate multiple files they all are on slightly different grids. My work involves tracing small artifacts like walls and ditches that get lost quickly if I process too much. Methods considered so far:

1. Create artificial LAS points at the exact corners of each original .las file and merge to create a file with the exact bounding box of the tiles
2. Do the same thing in Whitebox after converting each .las file to .shp

Both methods seem to work but require more automation then I have the skills for. If there is some way I am missing to just make each instance of LiDAR interpolation in Whitebox adhere to a grid that I set that would be much easier.